# App crashes after calling intent variable

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm passing info from one activity to another but there is a statement that isn't allowing it to happen, I'm unsure why though, could someone help, please?

Activity1(Kotlin based)

```
val spinnerMod = findViewById<View>(R.id.spinner_searchMod) as Spinner
val intent = Intent(this@AddModActivity, EditImportActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("module", listMod[spinnerMod.selectedItemPosition].ID)
startActivity(intent)
```

Activity2(Java based)

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String module = intent.getParcelableExtra("module").toString();
```

The line causing the issue is `String module = intent.getParcelableExtra("module").toString();`

Comment: Please paste the logcat too.

Comment: Why you are using `getParcelableExtra`. As you try to get string data, use getString method.

Comment: What is the type of `listMod[spinnerMod.selectedItemPosition].ID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `getParcelableExtra`. You can directly use

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String module = intent.getStringExtra("module");
```